# How to automatically compile and run xtext mydsl application from eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, dsl, xtext, xtend

I designed a small DSL in Xtext and wrote a sample DSL application that is successfully converted to C++ code by using Xtend code generator. What I would like is to be able to click "Run" inside Eclipse and then to automatically compile the generated .cpp file and run it. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The first what comes in my mind is to install the CDT plugin and get C++ sources compiled, generally. 
Then, you may add the CDT nature to your project where the. C++ code was generated in.
After that, use the CDT menu actions to compile and run the code.